# Captured still image in the surface view is getting reset by live camera when resuming the activity

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview, android-camera2

I am using custom surface view to capture the image in android. After clicking the image I need to preview the captured image with Retake, Use Photo button options. Until this everything is working fine.

When I lock and unlock my screen this captured image preview is reset by the live camera since camera.startPreview() is called in the onResume. If this method call is removed from onResume, then only black screen is visible.

This is my code on onResume

```
   @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (camera == null) {
        initializeCamera();
    } else {
            try {
                camera.startPreview();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
            }
    }
    sensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    sensorManager.registerListener(this, magneticField, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}
```

This is surfaceCreated method

```
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    try {
        surfaceView.getHolder().setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceView.getHolder());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to preserve the last captured image in surface onresume?

Answer (score 0):

I use this to preserve the image captured on screen

```
//you can omit this as in onresume() you re initialise your camera if null
yourCameraSurfaceView.yourCamera=null;

//remove Callback from holder when you capture the image
yourCameraSurfaceView.yourHolder.removeCallback(yourCameraSurfaceView);
```

Comment: I have removed callback after capturing image -    surfaceView.getHolder().removeCallback(CameraActivity.this);.. Still the captured image is gone on onresume

Comment: You can then write a condition to start preview in onresume(), if image has been captured you don't need to start camera preview in that case , sorry for the late reply brother